# What's the best way to reinstall Ubuntu on a partition already used for Ubuntu, but seemingly empty?

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation

On my dual boot computer (XP/Ubuntu) with a 500gb drive, I recently had someone remove a virus from Windows XP. Although I asked him to leave the Ubuntu partition as it is, the partition seems still to be there, but is not available any more. Disk check sais the partition is "healthy", and calls it a logical drive. I'd like to keep Ubuntu; I found it very useful besides the fact that I obviously will have to stop using XP.

My questions are:

- Would a new installation install into the current Ubuntu partition?
- Should I proceed as if it's a normal installation?
- Would it be possible to run a normal installation and leave XP there as before, or should I upgrade XP to 7 first?

Im sure these are basic questions, but I am a relatively inexperienced.

Thank you

Comment: I'm not sure we can answer that without a look at the partition table.. Can you link to a screenshot of gparted?

Answer (score 0):

> Would a new installation install into the current Ubuntu partition?

Ubuntu will be installed onto that partition which you tell it to install. It can be either that old partition (and it will be erased if you install there) or new. For further information, read [How do I install Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu)

> Should I proceed as if it's a normal installation?

If you want to install Ubuntu, there is one straightforward way. Just *install* it. But you  might want to repair your existing installation. For the insight, read [How can I repair grub? (How to get Ubuntu back after installing Windows?)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows)

> Would it be possible to run a normal installation and leave XP there as before, or should I upgrade XP to 7 first?

If you want to upgrade Windows, it is better to upgrade it before you deal with Ubuntu. But if you want to leave it as is, you can do it. Probably you'll like Ubuntu so much that you decide not to return to Windows anymore.